# Headless WordPress – Issue with plugin path

Tags: api, site-url, home-url, headless

Working on my first decoupled site. Backend is handled by WordPress and lives on the subdomain `admin.mydomain.com` and the frontend lives at `mydomain.com`.

The first issue I saw with the headless approach, was that all permalinks referred to `admin.mydomain.com`. I wanted to change that so that the backend referenced to my frontend.

So I changed my config from:
`WP_HOME='http://admin.mydomain.test'`
`WP_SITEURL='http://admin.domain.test/wp'`

to:
`WP_HOME='http://mydomain.test'`
`WP_SITEURL='http://admin.domain.test/wp'`

which sorted my issue with the permalinks, but now I'm getting console errors on the WP dashboard because the plugins can't find the resources they need, for example ACF:

```
index.php:63 GET http://mydomain.test/app/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/assets/css/acf-global.css?ver=5.8.4 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

What would be the proper course of action to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quick and dirty fix looks like this (please note that I use Roots [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/), so it differs from a vanilla WP install).

1. In .env add this line `WP_HOME_ADMIN='http://admin.mydomain.test'`
2. In application.php add this line, preferable just after where `WP_HOME` is
   defined: `Config::define('WP_HOME_ADMIN', env('WP_HOME_ADMIN'));`
3. Somewhere after where `CONTENT_DIR` is defined, add this line: `Config::define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', Config::get('WP_HOME_ADMIN') . Config::get('CONTENT_DIR') .'/plugins');`

Answer (score 4):

I understand the question and answer are from more than a year ago, but I just wanted to add some additional information in hopes it might be useful for future visitors of this Question.

---

Recently, while setting up a Headless WordPress CMS with Roots Bedrock, I came across the same issue and solved it with a slightly different version of your solution. I applied points 1 and 2 exactly the same, but did 3 a bit different.
Instead of adding the new line, I changed the declaration of the WP_CONTENT_URL constant from this:

```
Config::define('WP_CONTENT_URL', Config::get('WP_HOME') . Config::get('CONTENT_DIR'));
```

to this:

```
Config::define('WP_CONTENT_URL', Config::get('WP_HOME_ADMIN') . Config::get('CONTENT_DIR'));
```

This solved the backend plugins paths and also the active theme's backend assets paths.

---

But there was one final error: The WordPress REST API endpoint wasn't accessible in the backend, because it was being generated with the `get_home_url()` function, which returns the REST API endpoint appended to the frontend URL, instead of the `get_site_url()`.

Looking for solutions for fixing the REST API URL I came across this [post answer](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-wp_home-and-wp_siteurl-causes-cors-error/) where the post author provides this filter function you can paste into your active theme's functions.php file for replacing the REST API URL's base with that of the backend URL:

```
/*
 * Fix Roots Bedrock WP REST API base endpoint
 */
add_filter( 'rest_url', function( $url ) {
    $pattern = '/(\S+)(\/wp\/?)$/';
    $siteURL = preg_replace( $pattern, '${1}', site_url() );
    $url = str_replace( home_url(), $siteURL, $url );
    
    return $url;
} );
```

The function replaces the Frontend URL with the Backend URL, and also removes the `/wp` part of the Roots Bedrock WordPress backend URL.

Comment: thanks for the add_filter method, highly needed =)

Comment: Nice. This should really be in the bedrock docs or go in their config to accommodate headless setups. That is all I use WordPress for in this day and age...